# why does 生 and 先生 have different tones when it's part of a word?

Tags: tones

The pinyin for 生 is: **shēng**.

The pinyin for 先生 is: xiān​**sheng​**.

why does the tone change when it's part of a word?

Comment: I could do no better than to direct you to this Site -- https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/pronunciation/Tone_change_rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chinese-speaking language prefers a sentence to have clear "low - hi" sounds between consecutive words for ease of pronouncing and listening. When two words in a phrase have the same tone, the second word is often pronounced shorter and faster (急促) with a lighter sound (輕聲). Therefore, 生 in 先(first tone)生(first tone) can be pronounced both as xiān​sheng​, and xiānshēng. Note the change of sound from normal tone to 輕聲 is not a rule, nor mandatory but a better practice.

將漢語中的音節弱化之後，聲調會變得又輕又短，此種音變即為輕聲。
輕聲的調值需要根據語境決定調值，所以輕聲音節不可能獨立存在。

例如：

第一聲+輕聲：釘子 叔叔 他的

第二聲+輕聲：鉗子 伯伯 誰的

第三聲+輕聲：剪子 姐姐 我的

第四聲+輕聲：刨子 妹妹 是的

https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E8%BC%95%E8%81%B2/5667261